# TensorBoard shows No image data was found

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I have implemented a NN for MNIST using TensorFlow. I want to show the result on the TensorBoard. Flowing are screenshots of the TensorBoard that I have implemented. But the **IMAGES** page shows "**No image data was found**".

What information should be shown here? I should ignore it?

[image]

[image]

[image]
**CODE**

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

tf.reset_default_graph()
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('data', one_hot=True)

batch_size = 100
learning_rate = 0.5
training_epochs = 5
logs_path = "C:/tmp/mlp"

with tf.name_scope('input'):
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 784], name="x-input")
    y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 10], name="y-input")
with tf.name_scope("weights"):
    W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))
with tf.name_scope("biases"):
    b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
with tf.name_scope("softmax"):
    y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)
with tf.name_scope('cross_entropy'):
    cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y), reduction_indices=[1]))
with tf.name_scope('train'):
    train_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cross_entropy)
with tf.name_scope('Accuracy'):
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
tf.summary.scalar("cost", cross_entropy)
tf.summary.scalar("accuracy", accuracy)
summary_op = tf.summary.merge_all()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("C:/tmp/mlp", sess.graph)
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        batch_count = int(mnist.train.num_examples / batch_size)
        for i in range(batch_count):
            batch_x, batch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
            _, summary = sess.run([train_op, summary_op], feed_dict={x: batch_x, y_: batch_y})
            summary_writer.add_summary(summary, epoch * batch_count + i)
        if epoch % 5 == 0:
            print("Epoch: ", epoch)
    print("Accuracy: ", accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels}))
    print("done")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only lines in your code that refer to a summary operation are:

```
tf.summary.scalar("cost", cross_entropy)
tf.summary.scalar("accuracy", accuracy)
```

These lines create 2 scalar summaries (and add the created summary to a default collection that contains every defined summary).

You're not defining any image summary (with `tf.summmary.image`) thus that tab in tensorboard will be empty.

Answer (score 0):

Just ignore them, Because you did save any tf.summary.image summary, Tensorboard won't show anything in this tab;